# Detect when elements are inside absolute positioned box

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a box, and I need to detect when elements are inside of it as the user scrolls the page.  It also needs to be responsive.

I had it working earlier, with window height and width etc, but the percentages became all screwed up depending on which device I was on.  So I instead decided to opt for using a fixed/absolute element and then somehow detect intersection/collision with other elements.

The absolute element css is

```
#windowBox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

[image]

Im trying to have the elements inside of it light up when they scroll into it.  And also, ideally....when the user clicks next or prev, have the next and prev elements come automatically into the box / slide up or down.

I've been at this for hours and I'm tearing my hair out.  It should be so simple!

I've tried this, but it doesn't work.  Well it kinda does, but not really.  When I resize the window, it gets all messed up.  And its also jumpy and glitchy.

Obviously for the resize thing, I need to recalculate the percentages to get it to work.  But I think using that absolute element and detcting intersection is the more logical way to go for me.

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
  gridTop = windowHeight * .3,
  gridBottom = windowHeight * .3,
  console.log(gridTop),
  console.log(gridBottom);
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var t = $(this);
  $('.formQuestion').each(function() {
    var thisTop = $(this).offset().top - t.scrollTop();
    if (thisTop > gridTop && (thisTop + $(this).height()) < gridBottom) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: have you tried anything related to it...?...if yes, share the code...

Comment: Yeah, just posted.  It seems to only function on some of the elements, and miss/skip others.  Which is wierd too

Comment: well I think I solved it anyways.... https://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/dya1bv2c/10/  but Im gonna use Midnight JS because its so smooth and looks awesome

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any kind of external `jQuery` library...just use **jQuery** `.offset().top` to get the collision of the divs

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  $(".item").each(function() {
    if ($(this).offset().top < $(".middle-bar").offset().top + $(".middle-bar").outerHeight() && $(this).offset().top > $(".middle-bar").offset().top - $(this).outerHeight()) {
      $(this).addClass("newClass");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("newClass");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  margin: 300px 0;
}

.item {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 0 50px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.middle-bar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.item.newClass {
  background: red;
  transform: scale(.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="middle-bar"></div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Midnight.js](http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/), that's what you're looking for i think.

Comment: Yes that looks awesome and exactly what I need, thanks

Comment: think I solved it.... https://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/dya1bv2c/10/  but Im probably gonna use this instead, cuz its so nice